# Highcharts stock chart not showing up with custom data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying out the highcharts stock chart. This is the official [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui), which works on data from this [URL](https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json):

[image]

I am trying out the same code with a slightly different data form, which I have tweaked in code to resemble exactly the same as in the official demo. This is the URL from which I am fetching the [data](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo), and this is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/mjzncbf5/) which tweaks that data to make it look like the official data.

[image]

```
var realData = data["Time Series (5min)"];
    
    for (var k in realData)
    {
        var someDate = new Date(k);
            someDate = someDate.getTime();

        var val = realData[k];
        var li = [];
      var vol = [];
      li.push(someDate);
      
      li.push(val["1. open"]);
      li.push(val["2. high"]);
      li.push(val["3. low"]);
      li.push(val["4. close"]);
      ohlc.push(li);
      
      vol.push(val["1. open"]);
      vol.push(val["5. volume"]);
      
      volume.push(vol);
    }
```

However, as you can see in the output, I am getting a blank pane and not the custom data based chart. Any pointer towards fixing this will be helpful.

Edit. Made some [changes](https://jsfiddle.net/mjzncbf5/1/) in the data tweaking based on an answer below, but still I get a weird looking vertical chart here. What I was expecting was a horizontal chart, since the stock value remains constant throughout the day:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values were strings and not numbers also first value of element in `volume` should be timestamp, if you switch your loop to this it works

```
    for (var k in realData)
    {
    
      var someDate = new Date(k);
      someDate = someDate.getTime();

      var val = realData[k];
      var li = [];
      var vol = [];
      li.push(someDate);
      
      li.push(val["1. open"]);
      li.push(val["2. high"]);
      li.push(val["3. low"]);
      li.push(val["4. close"]);
      ohlc.push(li.map(x=>Number(x)));
      
      vol.push(someDate);
      vol.push(Number(val["5. volume"]))
      
      volume.push(vol);
    }
```

also don't use `var` and preferably don't mutate everything

Comment: Thanks. That almost works. Except that in Chrome (and Edge), I see a nearly blank chart with a think blue colored vertical line at the far right, hovering near which I can see a tooltip, while in Safari, I continue to see the same blank canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/mjzncbf5/1/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to converting string values to numbers, you need to reverse your data order.

```
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length,
        i = 0;

    var realData = data["Time Series (5min)"];

    for (var k in realData) {
        var someDate = new Date(k);
        someDate = someDate.getTime();

        var val = realData[k];
        var li = [];
        var vol = [];
        li.push(someDate);

        li.push(Number(val["1. open"]));
        li.push(Number(val["2. high"]));
        li.push(Number(val["3. low"]));
        li.push(Number(val["4. close"]));
        ohlc.push(li);

        vol.push(someDate);
        vol.push(Number(val["5. volume"]))
        volume.push(vol);
    }

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        ...,
        series: [{
            ...,
            data: ohlc.reverse(),
        }, {
            ...,
            data: volume.reverse()
        }]
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/21aw98j7/